# Odd method behaviour with optional first hash parameter and keyword_args

Tags: ruby, hash, optional-parameters, keyword-argument

I have the following method:

```
def test(first_param = nil, keyword_arg: nil)
  puts "first_param: #{first_param}"
  puts "keyword_arg: #{keyword_arg}"
end
```

All the following calls do what I expect them to do:

```
test(:something)
#=> first_param: something
#   keyword_arg:

test(nil, keyword_arg: :keyword_arg)
#=> first_param:
#   keyword_arg: keyword_arg

test({ first_param: :is_a_hash }, keyword_arg: :is_still_working)
#=> first_param: {:first_param=>:is_a_hash}
#   keyword_arg: is_still_working
```

But omitting the optional `keyword_arg` and passing a hash as first argument gives me an error:

```
test(first_param: :is_a_hash)
#=> test.rb:1:in `test': unknown keyword: first_param (ArgumentError)
#           from test.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

I'd expect it to set `first_param` to `{ first_param: :is_hash }` and `keyword_arg` being `nil`.

It seems it is interpreting every hash as keyword arg:

```
test(keyword_arg: :should_be_first_param)
#=> first_param:
#   keyword_arg: should_be_first_param
```

This should have set `first_param` to `{ keyword_arg: :should_be_first_param }`, leaving `keyword_arg` `nil` in my opinion.

Is this a parser bug or expected behaviour? Tested on ruby 2.3.0 and 2.2.4.

---

Edit: Making the first parameter *mandatory* and everything works like I'd expect to:

```
def test_mandatory(first_param, keyword_arg: nil)
  puts "first_param: #{first_param}"
  puts "keyword_arg: #{keyword_arg}"
end

test_mandatory(first_param: :is_a_hash)
#=> first_param: {:first_param=>:is_a_hash}
#   keyword_arg:

test_mandatory(keyword_arg: :should_be_first_param)
#=> first_param: {:keyword_arg=>:should_be_first_param}
#   keyword_arg:
```

I'd expect making a parameter optional does not change the way parameters are parsed.

I opened an [issue on bugs.ruby-lang.org](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11967), then the devs can clear up whether it is intended like this or a side effect of kword args.

Comment: "*This should have set `first_param` to `{ keyword_arg: :should_be_first_param }`, leaving `keyword_arg` `nil` in my opinion.*"--Why? Wouldn't you expect it to be ambiguous?

Comment: I only give one parameter to the method. When it is not a hash, it sets `first_param` (`test(:something)`). But if the parameter is a hash, it does not set `first_param` but interprets the hash as keyword arguments. Why is the behaviour depending on the type of the parameter? This is not logical (for me at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expected according to [Marc-Andre Lafortune's reply](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11967#note-3):

> This behavior may be surprising but it is intentional.
>
> It boils down to giving priority to filling keyword arguments first
>   instead of filling unnamed parameters. It is actually the only
>   possible way to go. Among other things, think about the following
>   example:
>
> ```
> def foo(*rest, bar: 42)
> end
> ```
>
> If we don't prioritize named arguments first, then there is simply no
>   way to specify a value for bar in this example!
>
> So Ruby checks that:
>
> - after all mandatory unnamed arguments are filled
> - if the last remaining argument is hash-like
> - and all its keys are symbols
> - and the method called uses keyword arguments
>
> => then that parameter is used for keyword arguments.
>
> Note the requirement on keys being symbols. This can yield even more
>   surprising if you pass a hash with some keys that are not symbols:
>
> ```
> def foo(a = nil, b: nil)
>   p a, b
> end
> foo(:b  => 42) # => nil, 42
> foo('b' => 42) # => {"b" => 42}, nil
> ```