# Why is ** optional when "splatting" keyword arguments?

Tags: ruby, method-invocation

Given this method definition:

```
def foo(a = nil, b: nil)
  p a: a, b: b
end
```

When I invoke the method with a single hash argument, the hash is always implicitly converted to keyword arguments, regardless of `**`:

```
hash = {b: 1}
foo(hash)     #=> {:a=>nil, :b=>1}
foo(**hash)   #=> {:a=>nil, :b=>1}
```

I can pass another (empty) hash as a workaround:

```
foo(hash, {}) #=> {:a=>{:b=>1}, :b=>nil}
```

**But**, this looks pretty cumbersome and awkward.

I would have expected Ruby to handle this more like arrays are handled, i.e.:

```
foo(hash)     #=> {:a=>{:b=>1}, :b=>nil}
foo(**hash)   #=> {:a=>nil, :b=>1}
```

And using literals:

```
foo({b: 1})   #=> {:a=>{:b=>1}, :b=>nil}
foo(b: 1)     #=> {:a=>nil, :b=>1}
foo(**{b: 1}) #=> {:a=>nil, :b=>1}
```

The current implementation looks like a flaw and the way I was expecting it to work seems obvious.

Is this an overlooked edge case? I don't think so. There's probably a good reason that it wasn't implemented this way.

Can someone enlighten me, please?

Comment: I had the same concern when I saw the same question that you just saw. But I know that keyword arguments have priority over regular optional arguments. What was a surprise to me was that it worked that way without `**`.

Comment: As for the priority part, a question has been raised on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653441, and this user seems to have also posted on Ruby core, and got an answer. According to Marc-Andre Lafortune, it is intentional. https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11967

Comment: I am not sure if this question is a duplicate (but I am not against it being closed. I am okay either way). The priority part is, but the `**` part isn't.

Comment: @sawa you're right, I've reopened and updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I've filed a bug report https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11993

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As for the lack of `**` part:

   My guess is that, to make method invocation simple, Ruby always once interprets the `key: value` form without the braces as a hash with omitted braces, whether it is actually going to be interpreted as such hash or as keyword arguments.

   Then, in order to interpret that as keyword arguments, `**` is implicitly applied to it.

   Therefore, if you had passed an explicit hash, it will not make difference to the process above, and there is room for it to be interpreted either as an actual hash or as keyword arguments.

   What happens when you do pass `**` explicitly like:

   ```
   method(**{key: value})
   ```

   is that the hash is decomposed:

   ```
   method(key: value)
   ```

   then is interpreted as a hash with omitted braces:

   ```
   method({key: value})
   ```

   then is interpreted either as a hash or as a keyword argument.
2. As for keyword arguments having priority over other arguments,  see this post on Ruby core: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11967.

Comment: IMO it should be handled at the parser level and just like array arguments, i.e. `foo(1, 2)`, `foo(*[1, 2])` and `foo([1, 2])` should behave like `foo(a: 1, b: 2)`, `foo(**{a: 1, b: 2})` and `foo({a: 1, b: 2})` respectively. It's very confusing that `foo({a: 1, b: 2})` gets converted.